# DEP0018 with express API

Tags: express, typeorm

Im getting this error code with express API with typeorm database:

```
(node:23162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
(node:23162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23162) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I used only this basic code in my app.ts and error is still on after sudo npm run build && sudo npm run start

```
createConnection().then(connection => {
    console.log("Try");
});
```

I tried also to change connection to async, but still not working.

Comment: which database you are using , mysql , postgres ?

Comment: Im using Postgres database

Comment: have you started your database server ?

Comment: Yeah, should be problem with ormconfig.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot connect to the database for whatever reason. It's not an issue with the ORM itself. Check your configurations, because most definitely that's where the problem resides.